# Docker permissions problem with jekyll image in WSL

Tags: docker, permissions, jekyll, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running docker using debian on WSL2, and I'm trying to run a local version of a website using a jekyll image. But, I seem to be running into permission issues with docker. I'm running:

```
docker run --rm --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" -p 4000:4000 jekyll/jekyll jekyll serve --trace
```

and this is the error message I'm getting:

```
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux-musl]
Configuration file: none
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /srv/jekyll/.jekyll-cache (Errno::EACCES)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `fu_mkdir'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `reverse_each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:184:in `dump'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:101:in `[]='
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:45:in `clear_if_config_changed'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:113:in `reset'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:33:in `initialize'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `each'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/gem/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from /usr/gem/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what to do in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It seems Docker volume does not have write permission to your $PWD.

- In Docker volume, user `jekyll` runs `jekyll serve` command and write output files on /srv/jekyll .

  - detail: https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/repos/jekyll/copy/all/usr/jekyll/bin/entrypoint
- Since you mount $PWD to /srv/jekyll , the user `jekyll` also needs write permission to $PWD.
- But your host computer would not have user `jekyll`, so the command would fail.

To solve this problem, you can change the user by specifying UID and GID as described here.
https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker#configuration

You need to check UID and GID of user on your host computer (which would have write permission to $PWD), then run command like below.

```
docker run --rm --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" -e JEKYLL_UID=1001 -e JEKYLL_GID=116 -p 4000:4000 jekyll/jekyll jekyll serve
```